# segmentation fault after free-ing node in hashtable

Tags: c, data-structures

> 

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define size 9900
int count = 1;

struct membership {
    char name[100];
    char gender[100];
    char code[100];
    int age;
    int weight;
    struct membership* next;
}*table[size];
typedef struct membership member;

member *newMember(char name[], char gender[], char code[], int age, int weight){
    member *node = (member*)malloc(sizeof(member));

    strcpy(node->name, name);
    strcpy(node->gender, gender);
    strcpy(node->code, code);
    node->age = age;
    node->weight = weight;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

int asciiSum(char str[]){
    int sum = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
        sum += str[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int hash(char code[]){
    return asciiSum(code)%size;
}

// insert recursive
member *insertRec(member *curr, char name[], char gender[], char code[], int age, int weight){
    if (!curr){
        return newMember(name, gender, code, age, weight);
    }

    curr->next = insertRec(curr->next, name, gender, code, age, weight);
    return curr;
}

// insert biasa
void insert(char name[], char gender[], char code[], int age, int weight){
    int key = hash(code);

    table[key] = insertRec(table[key], name, gender, code, age, weight);
}

void viewMember(){

    printf("| %-5s | %-20s | %-20s | %-20s | %-20s | %-15s |\n", 
    "no", "member name", "member age", "member weight", "member gender", "member code");

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        member *curr = table[i];
        while (curr) {
            printf("| %-5d | %-20s | %-20d | %-20d | %-20s | %-15s |\n", 
    ++j, curr->name, curr->age, curr->weight, curr->gender, curr->code);
        curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

}
member *searchRec(member *curr, char *code){
    if (!curr) return NULL;
    if(!strcmp(curr->code, code))return curr;
    return searchRec(curr->next, code);
}

member *deleteRec(member *curr, char *code){
    if (!curr) return NULL;
    if (!strcmp(curr->code, code)){
        free(curr);
        return curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = deleteRec(curr->next, code);
    return curr;
}

void deleteProduct(char *code){
    int key = hash(code);
    member *node = searchRec(table[key], code);
    if (!node) {
        printf("%s not found\n", code);
        return;
    }
    printf("Deleted %s\n", node->name);
    table[key] = deleteRec(table[key], code);
}


int main(){

    insert("tono", "male", "61TOM102", 21, 40);
    insert("tini", "female", "61TIF102", 21, 40);
    insert("didi", "male", "102DIM102", 21, 40);

    deleteProduct("61TOM102");

    viewMember();

    return 0;
}
```

The code above will produce zsh: segmentation fault.

What i expected : tono node got freed and the array got printed as normal but without tono

What actually resulted : zsh: segmentation fault

i think the error is either in deleteRec function or viewMember function.

i think after i free(curr) it somehow still there but as an invalid memory ?

i'm really stumped, can someone give me a hint ?

Thank you in advance

PS. when i try running the code on online compiler there's no problem, is the problem with my hardware ?

Comment: Your `free(curr); return curr->next;` is *undefined behaviour* because what `curr` points to is no longer valid.

Comment: member *temp = curr->next;
free(curr);
return temp;


I did that and it works now

Comment: did i do a correct move ? @WeatherVane

Comment: Yes, save a copy first. I didn't look at any of the other code though.